# Não inserir sequência de dados nulos em Loop POST ReactJs

Tags: javascript, react

Estou fazendo a inserção de uma tabela no Mysql com um Loop, caso o usuário não digite nada nos dois campos: "quantidadeUsada" e "numeroLote" do mesmo index, não quero salvar no banco de dados, teria alguma solução para isso?

Dei uma olhada no método delete(), porém não sei se é correto, mas tentei implementar conforme no código.

```js
const id_Prod = prods.map(prod => {
  return prod.produtoNfe_id;
});

for (var i = 0; i < id_Prod.length; i++) {


  if (quantidadeUsada[i] === "" && (numeroLote[i] === undefined || numeroLote[i] === "")) {

    delete(quantidadeUsada[i], numeroLote[i], id_ProdNfe[i], consumidor_id[i]);
  }

  api.post('/consumidor/produto', {
    quantidadeUsada: quantidadeUsada[i],
    numeroLote: numeroLote[i],
    fk_consumidor_id: consumidor_id,
    fk_produtoNfe_id: id_Prod[i]
  }).catch(error => {
    alert("Não foi possível fazer a inserção das Informações, Por favor tente novamente mais tarde. ");
  });
}
```

```html
<ul className="prods-list">
  {prods.map((prod, index) => (
  <li key={prod.modelo}>
    <label htmlFor="Modelo">Modelo</label>
    <input name="Modelo" type="text" value={prod.Modelo} disabled/>
    <label htmlFor="quantidadeDisponível">Quantidade Disponível</label>
    <input name="quantidadeDisponível" type="text" value={prod.quantidadeComprada} disabled/>

    <div key={index}>
      <label htmlFor={`quantidadeUsada-${index+1}`}>Quantidade Aplicada (Em Metros)</label>
      <input name="quantidadeUsada" type="number" id={`quantidadeUsada-${index+1}`} onChange={(e)=> onChangeQtdUsada(e, index)} step="any" min="0.1" placeholder="Ex: 1.2"/>

      <label htmlFor={`numeroLote-${index+1}`}>Número do Lote</label>
      <input name="numeroLote" type="text" id={`numeroLote-${index+1}`} maxLength="20" onChange={(e)=> onChangeNrmLote(e, index)}/>
    </div>
  </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Não me parece o ideal você fazer um `post` para cada item dentro de um laço de repetição, mas falando sobre a sua dúvida... Não seria melhor `if (valido) { post }` ao invés de `if (invalido) { delete } post`?

Comment: Teria alguma outra forma de inserir elementos de uma lista sem um laço de repetição?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que `delete` somente aceita um valor por vez:

```
delete quantidadeUsada[i];
delete numeroLote[i];
delete id_ProdNfe[I];
delete consumidor_id[i];
```

O resto funcionaria.  Mais como *@Rafael Tavares* falou.  O certo era mandar todos produtos juntos em uma requisição invés de criar um Ajax para cada um individual.  Isso pode passar o servidor se teu site crescer no futuro.